# Use Spring's TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy in code, not xml

Tags: java, spring, jooq, spring-transactions

I'm trying to [get jOOQ transactions to work](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.13/manual/getting-started/tutorials/jooq-with-spring/), except using code instead of XML configuration. I think it should be as simple as

```
// inside @Configuration annotated class
@Bean
public DataSource makeTransactionAware(DataSource fromConnectionPool) {
  return new TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy(fromConnectionPool);
}
```

except, I need to tell Spring that the injected `DataSource` is not the same one as returned from the method. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Bean custom naming & qualifier should do the work for you.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-qualifier-annotation

```
@Bean(name = "txAwareDS")
public DataSource makeTransactionAware(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource fromConnectionPool) {
    return new TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy(fromConnectionPool);
}
```

Example code is just a starting point.

Comment: OK, this is a good start. Now, which names do I need for the qualifier and the new bean, so that they will be used in the right places? Those are all configured by Spring itself, I have no control over them.

Comment: Then maybe operate with @Primary annotation? Do you want to wire both beans ("dataSource" and "txAwareDS") to specified places? So in one case (which is a Spring OOTB functionality) you do need transaction awareness, but in other situtation (which is also a Spring OOTB functionality) you do want to use the simple dataSource?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Spring configuration file](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.13/manual/getting-started/tutorials/jooq-with-spring/#N5D8BB) shared

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" >
    <!-- These properties are replaced by Maven "resources" -->
   <property name="url" value="${db.url}" />
   <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}" />
   <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
   <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
</bean>
<bean id="transactionAwareDataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy">
        <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
 </bean>
```

will be configured as

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
public class DataSourceConfig{

    @Value("${db.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${db.password}")
    private String password;
    @Value("${db.url}")
    private String url;

        @Bean
        public DataSource dataSource() {
            BasicDataSource basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
            basicDataSource.setDriverClassName("<driver class name>"); // Spring will load the driver discovered if not specified explicitly.
            basicDataSource.setUsername(username);
            basicDataSource.setPassword(password);
            basicDataSource.setUrl(url);
         return basicDataSource;
        }

        @Bean
        public TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy transactionAwareDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
            return new TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy(dataSource)
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps